# How to skip processing an element of an array if it is in another array? (C)

Tags: arrays, c, unique, nested-loops

Let `array1` and `array2` be two arrays of structure instances, allocated with the malloc array function.
`array1_totlength` and `array2_totlength` are the number of elements into the array.

I would like to perform an operation `func1()` on every element of `array1`, except those present in `array2`.

```
for (int bl= 0; bl < array1_totlength; bl++)
    {
      /* If this element is in array_2, skip it.*/
      for (int l= 0; l < array2_totlength; l++)
      {
        if (array2[l] == array1[bl])
        {?????}
        
      }
      func1(array1[bl]);
      
    }
```

Note that this is  a simplified version of the problem; in my actual case every element of `array2` has a pointer to an element of `array1`. The code adds a new element to `array2` (through memory reallocation), which has its pointer to the corresponding `array1` element. I need to skip creating the elements that have been pointed to already; an alternative would be to scrap `array2` entirely and make it from scratch, but I am not leaning towards this option, because it makes no sense to do it again if I had done it previously, it would just unnecessarily slow down the program.

Answer (score 2):

Simply use a variable to indicate if it's found. This works and also signals the intent to anyone reading the code.

```
for (int bl= 0; bl < array1_totlength; bl++)
    {
      bool found = false;
      /* Search for the element in array_2 */
      for (int l= 0; l < array2_totlength; l++)
      {
        if (array2[l] == array1[bl])
        {
           found = true;
           break; /* stop searching */
        }        
      }
      if (!found) {
        func1(array1[bl]);
      }
      
    }
```

Comment: sorry! i am new here so dont really have perfection in my answers and misses out some points

Answer (score 1):

For example you can write

```
for ( int bl = 0; bl < array1_totlength; bl++ )
{
      /* If this element is in array_2, skip it.*/
      int l = 0;

      while ( l != array2_totlength && array2[l] != array1[bl] ) ++l;

      if ( l == array2_totlength ) func1(array1[bl]);
      
}
```

Comment: This is actually so smart! Actually along with `func1` I have a if-else with another function, so I implemented the last line like this: 

`if ( l != array2_totlength ) {continue;}` 

Beside this, you helped me so much, thank you Vlad ✨

Edit: Oh I can't get the returns/new line to work in this comment, sorry...

Comment: @hieverybody Instead of using the continue statement like if ( l != array2_totlength ) {continue}; It would be better to write if ( l == array2_totlength ) { // calls of functions and any other required code}.

Comment: I see, can I ask you why? I thought one should avoid more nesting levels

Comment: @hieverybody The code after the inner for loop is executed if the condition is satisfied. And there is a check of the condition in the if statement. Using the continue statement is redundant.

Answer (score -2):

```
for (int bl= 0; bl < array1_totlength; bl++)
{
  /* If this element is in array_2, skip it.*/
  for (int l= 0; l < array2_totlength; l++)
  {
    if (array2[l] == array1[bl])
    continue;
    
  }
  func1(array1[bl]);
  
}
```

Always remember two things in an array

1. continue; It helps to skip one step
2. break; it help us to come out of loop .
   hope this solution helped you.
   happy coding ;)

Comment: This doesn't work - the `continue;` will continue the inner loop, not the outer one. Ditto for the answer provided by someone with an incredibly similar username.

Answer (score -5):

to solve your problem you can do the following

```
    for (int bl = 0; bl < array1_totlength; bl++)
     {
      /* If this element is in array_2, skip it. */ 
     for (int l = 0; l < array2_totlength; l++)
     {
          if (array2[l] == array1[bl])
             {continue;}
         else{
               func1(array1[bl]);
              }
         }
     }
```

Comment: `func1(array1[bl])` is always executed

Comment: i corrected it now

Comment: Not only is `func1()` always executed, it is executed multiple times for each element. This is worse than wrong.